# Spring Cloud Stream Reactive - which kafka-binder is appropriate in case of reactive stream pipeline?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We are using **reactive spring cloud stream** with the Kafka. Any suggestions on using the right binder? which one is most suitable for the reactive pipeline?

1. spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka
2. spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams

Obviously, we would love and wish if we get **reactive-kafka-binder**. Since all our apps end-to-end (Source, Processor and Sink) are built on reactive stream pipeline.

> **Reactive kafka** will be the best suitable, since we are using entire pipeline as a reactive. To make the end-to-end pipeline reactive.  Any plans of providing such reactive-kafka-binder in the spring?

To make it simple, currently we are using the **reactive spring cloud stream** with the **spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka** and **not kafka-streams.** Looking forward to your answers. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

***spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive***

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're using the right dependency - `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`.

I'd suggest using the `spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka` dependency that comes from the `spring-cloud-stream-dependencies` / `spring-cloud-dependencies-parent` pom, though.

```
    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>
```

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```